# how to pass a parameter to after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create an object(say Y) of another model as soon as object(say X) of one model is created. Object Y needs to take some attributes of object X that was created. So the after_save method basically should have code equivalent to New Y(Object X). My doubt is how to pass the object X as a parameter to the New() call.

Answer (score 1):

You could always create Y and then assign values to it's properties, then call save on Y.

```
def after_save_func
  y = y.new
  y.val1 = self.val1
  y.val2 - self.val2
  y.save
end
```

But this method is going to be called after every save, which seems wrong more like after_create would be the best?

Comment: ya this is so easy. dumb me. but why wouldnt this work after every save ?

Comment: Do you feel like creating a new object every save? What if a object gets saved 5 times, you would then have 5 Y objects for 1 X object. But maybe it makes sense for your use cases

Comment: ya thanks for pointing that out. Another problem I can now think of is how to change the values of the attributes of the new object if the parent object values are being changed ?

Comment: @user3311539 why not give the two models a relationship so you can access Y thru X? Is it a 1 to 1?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the below code i Wrote finally is a good solution by design standards or not. But it seems to work for my requirements:

```
def create_wc
Workcategory.delete_all(rfsestimationid: self.id)
@workcategory = Workcategory.new()
@workcategory.name = self.name + "_" + "#{self.number}" + "_Analysis"
@workcategory.hours = self.rfstaskset.analysis_hours
@workcategory.rfsestimationid = self.id
@workcategory.save

@workcategory = Workcategory.new()
@workcategory.name = self.name + "_" + "#{self.number}" + "_Design"
@workcategory.hours = self.rfstaskset.design_hours
@workcategory.rfsestimationid = self.id
@workcategory.save

@workcategory = Workcategory.new()
@workcategory.name = self.name + "_" + "#{self.number}" + "_Test"
@workcategory.hours = self.rfstaskset.test_hours
@workcategory.rfsestimationid = self.id
@workcategory.save

@workcategory = Workcategory.new()
@workcategory.name = self.name + "_" + "#{self.number}" + "_Build"
@workcategory.hours = self.rfstaskset.test_hours
@workcategory.rfsestimationid = self.id
@workcategory.save


@workcategory = Workcategory.new()
@workcategory.name = self.name + "_" + "#{self.number}" + "_UATSupport"
@workcategory.hours = self.rfstaskset.UATSupport_hours
@workcategory.rfsestimationid = self.id
@workcategory.save

@workcategory = Workcategory.new()
@workcategory.name = self.name + "_" + "#{self.number}" + "_DepSupport"
@workcategory.hours = self.rfstaskset.DepSupport_hours
@workcategory.rfsestimationid = self.id
@workcategory.save

end
```

The workcategory objects are deleted each time, the parent object is updated and rebuilt in the above code.
This code is executed as an after_save operation.